# Spot size for objective (not infinity corrected)

Tags: optics, laser, diffraction, lenses, imaging

A fundamental axiom of imaging in optics is the resolving power of the lens system, which is directly related to the smallest possible spot a lens can form. For an ideal lens with a numerical aperture $NA$, if we uniformly illuminate the input pupil with a laser beam at wavelength $\lambda$, then the spot size at the focus of the lens is:

\begin{equation}
w_0 = 0.61\frac{\lambda}{NA}
\end{equation}

This is an important manifestation of physical optics: the diffraction-limited spot. I believe that this equation holds only if we assume that the incoming rays are *parallel* - that is, we have a collimated input beam. If there is some divergence in the incoming beam, then the spot size deviates from the theoretical value.

For an *infinity-corrected* objective lens, we can use the same logic to determine best focusing performance: just make sure that you have a collimated input beam, and you will achieve the smallest spot, defined by the equation above.

For an objective that is *not* infinity corrected, the system is designed to take a diverging light source located at 1 focal distance $f_1$ in front of the lens (object plane) and image that object at a distance $f_2$ after the lens.

**I want to know how to form the smallest possible spot using a laser beam and a lens that is not infinity corrected.** Is the behavior similar to the infinity-corrected system, where minimized input divergence would yield the smallest spot? Or, should I introduce a specific divergence to get the smallest spot? If I can, does the equation above apply?

Note that I'm not interested in imaging. I have a laser beam that I can focus at some location before the non-infinity-corrected lens (perhaps I can focus to some spot at $f_1$ before my non-infinity-corrected lens), so that the spot formed by the non-infinity-corrected lens is minimized.

[image: The top diagram shows an infinity-corrected objective lens system: collimated light is brought down to a minimal spot at 1 focal distance f in front of the lens (wavevector k shows the direction of propagation. A system that is not infinity-corrected is shown in the lower diagram: light emanating from a source at a specified location f1 is focused to a small spot at distance f2 after the lens.]